# Linker errors in a Windows Forms Application

Tags: c++, c++-cli, linker-errors

I'm trying to make my first Windows Forms Application. I'm trying to make an SQL connection, so i inserted my SQL function, which worked perfectly in a console application. I rewrited it a little bit, but right now, i am getting linker errors, and i don't know why.

Could someone help me, what i am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Erros:

`Error  3   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000023) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLGetData(void *,unsigned short,short,void *,long,long *)" (?SQLGetData@@$$J224YGFPAXGF0JPAJ@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ) Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  4   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000024) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLFetch(void *)" (?SQLFetch@@$$J14YGFPAX@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ) Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  5   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000025) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLRowCount(void *,long *)" (?SQLRowCount@@$$J18YGFPAXPAJ@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ) Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  6   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000026) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLNumResultCols(void *,short *)" (?SQLNumResultCols@@$$J18YGFPAXPAF@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)  Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  7   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000027) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLDisconnect(void *)" (?SQLDisconnect@@$$J14YGFPAX@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)   Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  8   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000028) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLFreeHandle(short,void *)" (?SQLFreeHandle@@$$J18YGFFPAX@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)    Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  9   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000029) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLExecDirectA(void *,unsigned char *,long)" (?SQLExecDirectA@@$$J212YGFPAXPAEJ@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)   Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  10  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00002A) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLSetStmtAttrW(void *,long,void *,long)" (?SQLSetStmtAttrW@@$$J216YGFPAXJ0J@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)  Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  11  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00002B) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLDriverConnectA(void *,struct HWND__ *,unsigned char *,short,unsigned char *,short,short *,unsigned short)" (?SQLDriverConnectA@@$$J232YGFPAXPAUHWND__@@PAEF2FPAFG@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)  Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  12  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00002C) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLSetConnectAttrW(void *,long,void *,long)" (?SQLSetConnectAttrW@@$$J216YGFPAXJ0J@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)    Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  13  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00002D) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLSetEnvAttr(void *,long,void *,long)" (?SQLSetEnvAttr@@$$J216YGFPAXJ0J@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)  Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  14  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00002E) "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLAllocHandle(short,void *,void * *)" (?SQLAllocHandle@@$$J212YGFFPAXPAPAX@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)   Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  15  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLGetData(void *,unsigned short,short,void *,long,long *)" (?SQLGetData@@$$J224YGFPAXGF0JPAJ@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)  Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  16  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLFetch(void *)" (?SQLFetch@@$$J14YGFPAX@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)  Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLRowCount(void *,long *)" (?SQLRowCount@@$$J18YGFPAXPAJ@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)  Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  18  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLNumResultCols(void *,short *)" (?SQLNumResultCols@@$$J18YGFPAXPAF@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)   Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  19  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLDisconnect(void *)" (?SQLDisconnect@@$$J14YGFPAX@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)    Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  20  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLFreeHandle(short,void *)" (?SQLFreeHandle@@$$J18YGFFPAX@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ) Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  21  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLExecDirectA(void *,unsigned char *,long)" (?SQLExecDirectA@@$$J212YGFPAXPAEJ@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)    Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  22  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLSetStmtAttrW(void *,long,void *,long)" (?SQLSetStmtAttrW@@$$J216YGFPAXJ0J@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)   Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  23  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLDriverConnectA(void *,struct HWND__ *,unsigned char *,short,unsigned char *,short,short *,unsigned short)" (?SQLDriverConnectA@@$$J232YGFPAXPAUHWND__@@PAEF2FPAFG@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)   Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  24  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLSetConnectAttrW(void *,long,void *,long)" (?SQLSetConnectAttrW@@$$J216YGFPAXJ0J@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ) Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  25  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLSetEnvAttr(void *,long,void *,long)" (?SQLSetEnvAttr@@$$J216YGFPAXJ0J@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)   Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  26  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" short __stdcall SQLAllocHandle(short,void *,void * *)" (?SQLAllocHandle@@$$J212YGFFPAXPAPAX@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall Test_WindowsForm::Form1::ExecuteSQLCommand(void)" (?ExecuteSQLCommand@Form1@Test_WindowsForm@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)    Test_WindowsForm.obj`

`Error  27  fatal error LNK1120: 24 unresolved externals    D:\testVS2008\Test_WindowsForm\Debug\Test_WindowsForm.exe`

Comment: If you're already using .NET, why not use [.NET's SQL facilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx)?

Comment: @ildjarn: Could you show me an example?

Comment: The [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx), [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx), etc. docs all come with plenty of examples...

Comment: Add `odbc32.lib` into your linker command line

Comment: @qehgt: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu! This cost me 2 hours :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `odbc32.lib` to your project's [linker inputs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx).